# jsPDF convert HTML string to PDF

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pdf

I am fetching HTML code from the server in typescript as HTMLElement (also tried string).

How do i convert this HTML code to PDF using jsPDF? I tried using html2canvas, to convert the HTML i fetch from the server to canvas, but an error i get is this:

```
Error: Element is not attached to a Document
```

I assume, it's because it is not inside of the DOM?

Is there a different way i can convert HTML string (with CSS) to a PDF?

This is my current code:

```
this.service
  .get(92)
  .subscribe((html: HTMLElement) => {
    //console.log(html);

    html2canvas(html).then((canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
      console.log(canvas);
    });

    /*const doc = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4');

    doc.html(html, {
      callback: function (doc) {
        doc.save();
      },
    });*/
  });
```

Comment: If its not attached to dom, can't you append it to html? Or use a div thats already in dom ?

Comment: @GowthamRajJ thanks a lot, didn't think of that! But theres another problem... there is only one page and there should be more and images aren't showing. Maybe doc.addImage isnt the correct method i should use. And doc.html renders everything way too big

Comment: In this example from their demo, http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/ they are able to show the image, is there any error in your console?

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i chose a different approach. It cost a lot more space, but i decided to go with puppeteer sharp on backend and it works much better